# SQL obtaining an average sale cost over multiple years

Tags: mysql

I have an sql query that will return the average sold price for a given property type at a particular year.

```
SELECT 
            `table`.Property AS 'Property',
            `table`.Year AS 'Year',
            AVG(`table`.`Value`) AS 'Average Sold Price'
            FROM
            `table`
            WHERE `table`.`Area` LIKE '%NW1%'
            AND `table`.`Property` LIKE '%F%'
            AND `table`.`Year` = '2011'
            GROUP BY `table`.Property,`table`.Year
            ORDER BY
            `table`.Property ASC
```

the output looks like this

```
| Property | Year | Average Sold Price
|    F     | 2011 | 440242.18137204903
```

on a look up at 2016

```
| Property | Year | Average Sold Price
|    F     | 2016 | 702453.9544754727
```

-- how would I alter the query to get a merged output - so something like this, try to reduce the number of calls etc..

```
| Property | Average Sold Price (2011) | Average Sold Price (2016)
|    F     | 440242.18137204903        | 702453.9544754727
```

Comment: it would be slower to get it as one row but if you remove `AND table.year='2011'` you'll get all years in multiple rows

Comment: The feature you need is a pivot - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: WHERE year IN(2011,1016) GROUP BY year ... as stated previously, handle the display issue in the presentation layer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
            `table`.Property AS 'Property',
            `table`.Year AS 'Year',
            AVG(`table`.`Value`) AS 'Average Sold Price'
            FROM `table`
            WHERE `table`.`Area` LIKE '%NW1%'
            AND `table`.`Property` LIKE '%F%'
            AND `table`.`Year` IN(2011,2016)
            GROUP BY `table`.Property,`table`.Year
            ORDER BY `table`.Property ASC
```

^ this has produced a usable output.

```
| Property | Year | Average Sold Price
|    F     | 2011 | 440242.18137204903
|    F     | 2016 | 702453.9544754727
```